# Flume HDFS sink with Kafka source - multiple files?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, flume

Flume HDFS sink configured as follows :

```
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /project/mgd/ 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = EMA_LOG%Y%m%d 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 86400 
#tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .json 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

produces three HDFS files daily (rollInterval = 86400). Is this a consequence of the number of flume agents configured on a cluster or the number of Kafka topic partitions which is configured as a source for this particular flume agent? Any suggestions on combining those files into one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running three flume agents then it will create 3 files, if you need only one file, then you have to run only one flume agent. Or else after it creates 3 files, you need to merge those files yourself, external to flume.